# How to have a range of numbers in an if/else statement Java

Tags: java

I'm learning Java through a series of explanations and exercises, and one of them was to create a program that would display a number grade (0-5) in accordance to a number of points (0–29, 30–34, 35–39, 40–44, 45–49, 50–60).

```
System.out.println("Type the points [0-60]: ");
double points = reader.nextDouble();
reader.nextLine();
if (points < 29) {
    System.out.println("Grade: FAILED.");
} else if (points <= 34) {
    System.out.println("Grade: 1.");
} else if (points <= 39) {
    System.out.println("Grade: 2.");
} else if (points <= 44) {
    System.out.println("Grade: 3.");
} else if (points <= 49) {
    System.out.println("Grade: 4.");
} else if (points >= 50) {
    System.out.println("Grade: 5.");
}
```

The program works in that it'll give the correct grade because of the overlap in commands, but is there any way to create a range of numbers or strings that could meet the condition of the if/else statement? For example, if the number entered is between 40-44 and so on. Detailed answer would be appreciated since I'm new.

Comment: You could inverse control in the if statements to make it more clear. But at first i would suggest you making new variable that would hold the grade, then after testing use one `System.out.println("Grade: "+gradeVar);`

Comment: Your ranges are strictly contiguous only if you use an `Integer`, not `Double` input. For example for the two ranges `0-29, 30-34` (assuming inclusive bounds) what grade is 29.5 meant to get?

Comment: The last `else if` should just be an `else`. The `if (points >= 50)` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test if number is between some values use logical operator AND for if statements like:

```
if(points>=40 && points <=45)
```

To get more clarity I would suggest you to make a control inversion like this:

```
    int grade;
    if(points >49){
        grade=5;
    }else if(points >44){
        grade=4;
    }else if(points >39){
        grade=3;
    }else if(points >34){
        grade=2;
    }else if(points >29){
        grade=1;
    }else{
        grade=0;

  }
    System.out.println("Gr: "+grade); //grade=0 = not passed
```

Comment: How is this really any different from the question? I don't see why flipping the order makes it any more clear. --- You did change to follow the text stating that grade is 0-5, good, but other than that...?

Comment: every condition checks if points are greater than (not using both `<` and `>`). It could go other way also and in the very end appy grade=5 in single else. But i consider it as easier to read than lots of conditions applied to single if. Yours and dasblinkenlight solutions are very good if someone wants to avoid `if`.

Comment: Well, question code should have used `else`, not `else if` on that last one, and was missing an `=` sign on 29, but your code ain't any better, using `>=` on first test and `>` on the other tests, and I think having an `else` at the end, rather than defaulting to initial value, is less *clear*.

Comment: depends on a context, but if you get `0` it any test you would know and here else is just useless :)
Yeah, I mostly use `else` in `if` statements and I usually make my variables as class fields or parts of the map as you proposed, but then I know whats the value of not initialized variable.

Comment: @Andreas edited as your suggestion, idk i thought about a performance a bit to not to make another testing statement if i am sure about output. 
Still, all depends on context.

Comment: Initializing `grade` to `0` then changing it, e.g. to `5`, is worse than an `else`, but given the general mantra of not performance tuning your code until needed (see these quotes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes), either is acceptable, performance-wise. --- BTW: You're missing an end-brace. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Divide the number by five, and make an array of twelve strings with the textual representation of the grade:

```
private static final String GRADE_FAILED = "FAILED";
private static final String GRADE_1 = "1";
private static final String GRADE_2 = "2";
private static final String GRADE_3 = "3";
private static final String GRADE_4 = "4";
private static final String GRADE_5 = "5";

private static String GradeStr[] = new {
    GRADE_FAILED // 0..4
,   GRADE_FAILED // 5..9
,   GRADE_FAILED // 10..14
,   GRADE_FAILED // 15..19
,   GRADE_FAILED // 20..24
,   GRADE_FAILED // 25..29
,   GRADE_1      // 30..34
,   GRADE_2      // 35..39
,   GRADE_3      // 40..44
,   GRADE_4      // 45..49
,   GRADE_5      // 50..54
,   GRADE_5      // 55..59
,   GRADE_5      // 60..64 // Only sixty matters
};

System.out.println("Grade:"+GradeStr[points/5]+".");
```

If you need more granularity, make a bigger array, divide by a smaller number or skip the division altogether, and set the constants in the positions that correspond to the grades that need to be printed. This lets you avoid the conditionals altogether.

**Important disclaimer:** this approach works best when the number of options is small - up to a hundred or so. When your problem allows for this approach, it is the fastest approach by far. In many cases, it is also the easiest one to read.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your code can only work if point block is the same size (or multiple of such). --- Also, in this case the sizes are 30, 5, 5, 5, 5, 11, so your last block is incorrect. You can't handle the value 60, unless of course you correct the code by adding an extra block.

Comment: @Andreas Handling numbers at different increments is what that last paragraph is about. There could be off-by-one problems in this code, it's only an illustration of the "how to replace an if-then-else chain with an array" principle.

Comment: I don't think this is generally a good pattern, because of the volatile nature of the array depending on whether the boundaries are evenly distributed. If numbers were 0-1000 with boundary at 101, 211, 421, and 831, this wouldn't be a good pattern.

Comment: @Andreas Please don't make this another problem: as stated, we have 60 numbers (that is **sixty** numbers, not a **thousand** numbers). Size very often matters a lot. This is one of these cases.

Comment: Agreed. But you missed part of my first comment. 0-60 is *61* numbers. You need an extra line with `,   GRADE_5      // 60..64`, otherwise 60 points will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException, and you probably shouldn't have that +1 in `(points+1)`.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't miss it: "There could be off-by-one problems in this code, it's only an illustration". But I edited the answer just in case someone else decides to split some hairs about an off-by-one error.

Comment: Sorry, I modified my comment after you saw it. Isn't the `+1` wrong? Shouldn't it just be `GradeStr[points/5]`. That will make it work perfectly for the question, without need of any disclaimers. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas The disclaimer is about expanding the range, not about the off-by-one. Having an extra element is still necessary, because grades use human counting, so they continue to 60.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `NavigableMap`, most commonly a `TreeMap`. The method used below is `floorEntry`. Quoting [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry%28K%29):

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key less than or equal to the given key, or `null` if there is no such key.

**Note:** Your code was missing an `=` sign on the 29 boundary, and the `points` value should be an integer.

**Changed** to use a grade (0-5), instead of the string used in question.

```
// Grade boundary is lower-inclusive (grade is 0-60)
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> gradeMap = new TreeMap<>();
gradeMap.put( 0, 0); //  0–29
gradeMap.put(30, 1); // 30–34
gradeMap.put(35, 2); // 35–39
gradeMap.put(40, 3); // 40–44
gradeMap.put(45, 4); // 45–49
gradeMap.put(50, 5); // 50+

System.out.println("Type the points [0-60]: ");
int points = reader.nextInt();
reader.nextLine();
int grade = gradeMap.floorEntry(points).getValue();
System.out.println("Grade: " + grade);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for

```
if( points<=44 && points>=40 )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a number is between two values, you would use an and in your if statement:

```
if (points >= 40 && points <= 44) {
    System.out.println("Grade: 3.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for a range within an if statement, you can do this:

```
if(points >= 0 && points <= 29)
```

This is by using `&&` (and) operator by combining conditions together.

But you don't really need to check for a range in any of the if-statements.
Doing what you currently have will be suffice.